# npgsql 7.0 c# select from function

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have updated from npgsql 6 to npgsql 7 and have to update the way I am querying the functions.
One simple function looks like the following

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION orders_daily_get(
    p_startdate date,
    p_enddate date)
    RETURNS TABLE (id integer, name text)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT orderid, ordername FROM orders WHERE orderdate BETWEEN p_startdate AND p_enddate;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Normally I have called the function as follows

```
using NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection = new("conn_string");

using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new("orders_daily_get", npgsqlConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

cmd.Parameters.Add(new() { ParameterName = "p_startdate", Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-07-01"), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Date });

cmd.Parameters.Add(new() { ParameterName = "p_enddate", Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-07-19"), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Date });

npgsqlConnection.Open();

using NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
  [... do something...]
}

npgsqlConnection.Close();
```

I have updated my command declaration as described in the release notes of npgsql 7

```
using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new("SELECT * FROM orders_daily_get($1,$2)", npgsqlConnection);
```

The error message is

> 08P01: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2'

Could somebody please support the correct call of a function in npgsql 7?

Comment: The original method was using a Stored Procedure while you updated code is not using a Stored Procedure.  Do you have a Stored Procedure "orders_daily_get"?

Comment: On sql side it was a function and it is still a function. The way npgsql handles the function call now (since 7.0 and without the Npgsql.EnableStoredProcedureCompatMode) is different, but I cannot figure out how the correct way should be with using parameters

Comment: See following : https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html

Comment: You're using the PG positional parameter placeholders in your SQL ($1, $2) - that's indeed recommended. But if you do that, remove the ParameterNames from your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer by my own.
I have mixed up positional parameters with named parameters in c#.

Instead of

```
using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new("SELECT * FROM orders_daily_get($1,$2)", npgsqlConnection);
```

it should be

```
using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new("SELECT * FROM orders_daily_get(@p_startdate,@p_enddate)", npgsqlConnection);
```

Or one has to remove the ParameterName from the parameter declaration and use the positional version

Instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new() { ParameterName = "p_startdate", Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-07-01"), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Date });
```

it has to be

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new() { Value = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-07-01"), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Date });
```

I prefer the first option, because you make sure that your functions receive correct data for the parameters by creating a "link" via their names.

Hope that helps some other users.

Cheers
Benjamin

Comment: I'd recommend going the other way. Keep $1 and $2 in your SQL, but remove ParameterName from your parameters. That makes Npgsql send native PG placeholders ($1, $2) rather than rewriting the SQL to do that (for more info, see https://www.roji.org/parameters-batching-and-sql-rewriting)